# Regular expression to remove the dot (.) from a number

Tags: java, regex

I want to write a regular expression in Java to remove the dot (.) from a number and all the numbers that come after it.

Example: 3.14

Need a regex to return only 3.

I'm trying to use this block:

```
String value = "3.14";
value = value.replaceAll("[[.]]", "");
System.out.println(value);
```

Obviously, it just removes the ".". I tried other matches like [[.*$]] to remove everything until the end of the line, but it is taking me nowhere.

I'm using this table (http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-regex/syntax.html), what I'm finding pretty good actually, and test its use.

Comment: Do you actually understand what `value.replaceAll("[[.]]", "")` does? The fact that you tried `"[[.*$]]"` as a regex suggests you do not.

Comment: @luk2302 You're right. I'm struggling to understand how it finds patterns in a string inwards and outwards, and also, how it searches for things from the beginning to a certain point, and from a certain point to the end

Comment: @luk2302 It is a good one. But I want to know how regex work in java

Answer (score 2):

The `[]` indicate a *character class*. `[[.]]` does end up matching just a `.`, although the outer `[]` is unnecessary in your case (and/or you could use a `\` instead).

To remove `.` followed by digits, match `.` and `\d+` (one or more digits). Because `.` means "any character," you have to escape it (`\.` or `[.]` work). Because `\` has special meaning in string literals, any backslashes for the regular expression need to be escaped as well (with another backslash). So:

```
value = value.replaceAll("\\.\\d+", "");
// Or: value = value.replaceAll("[.]\\d+", "");
// Or: value = value.replaceAll("[.][0-9]+", ""); (avoiding backslashes entirely)
```

If you want to do this only after a digit (so not in `"Blah .123"), you can add a *positive lookbehind* at the beginning to require a digit:

```
value = value.replaceAll("(?<=\\d)\\.\\d+", "");
// Or: value = value.replaceAll("(?<=\\d)[.]\\d+", "");
// Or: value = value.replaceAll("(?<=\\d)[.][0-9]+", ""); (avoiding backslashes entirely)
```

These various features are described in the [`Pattern` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Example ([live copy](https://ideone.com/0x1Xcd)):

```
class Example
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        String value = "Testing 3.14 testing 2.45534 testing .123 testing";
        System.out.println(value.replaceAll("\\.\\d+", ""));
        System.out.println(value.replaceAll("[.]\\d+", ""));
        System.out.println(value.replaceAll("[.][0-9]+", ""));

        value = "Testing 3.14 testing 2.45534 testing .123 testing";
        System.out.println(value.replaceAll("(?<=\\d)\\.\\d+", ""));
        System.out.println(value.replaceAll("(?<=\\d)[.]\\d+", ""));
        System.out.println(value.replaceAll("(?<=\\d)[.][0-9]+", ""));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Testing 3 testing 2 testing  testing
Testing 3 testing 2 testing  testing
Testing 3 testing 2 testing  testing
Testing 3 testing 2 testing .123 testing
Testing 3 testing 2 testing .123 testing
Testing 3 testing 2 testing .123 testing
```

Notice how the second three didn't replace `.123`, because there was no digit in front of it. The first three did.